# How to create a document with previously used developer name?

Tags: document, developername

I am getting an error 'Unique name already used'while creating a document with  which was deleted previously.

I want to re create the same document with the same developer name. Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: If the document was part of a managed package, and that document was uploaded as a release, then subsequently deleted, that developer name is forever locked out. The only way to release the name is to submit a request to rollback to the all versions up until the inclusion of that element to beta packages, which will then allow you to reuse the element. You can't do this if any version that would be rolled back is already installed in at least one other org (unless you have all of them uninstalled). In short, you're probably stuck.

Answer (score 1):

you are unable to create document because you document may still exist in organization recycle bin. You have to delete it from org recycle bin.

In case if your document exist in recycle bin, undelete it and on detail page click "replace document" on detail page to replace the document.

Comment: I cleared the recycle bin already but still i am facing the issue.

Comment: The only reasom is this developname is still in organization or a part of installed package

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old thread but the issue is still actual and I've got a way to workaround.

So the issue at hand is the same - document deleted and the recycle bin emptied. So no way to undelete anymore without invlolving support or whatsoever.

But it is required to create the document with exact same name.

So what worked is to make a change set from another org in the environment that had that document. In my case I've moved the document to sandbox from production. And the document was successfully deployed.